# Where is the midrash of "300 days of Tefillin?"

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, tefilin, aleph-bet-letters, gematria-numerology

According to various Rishonim and Acharonim who are listed in R' Binyomin Shlomo Hamburger's "Shorshei Minhag Ashkenaz Volume 5," there is a Midrash that states that the Shin on Tefillin boxes alludes to the 300 (Shin is the gematria letter for 300) days a year when we put on Tefillin. However, the exact source for this midrash is not given.

Where is this Midrash?

Comment: I struggle to see how it’s possible to have 300 days a year on which we put on Tefillin.

Comment: @DonielF It works if you use the solar year, assume it doesn't start and end on Shabbos, are in Chutz Laaretz, and wear tefillin on Chol Hamoed.  365 days total - 52 days of Shabbos - 13 days of Yom Tov.

Comment: @Heshy And assuming that it's a normal year, not a leap one. Why would a Midrash base the Hebrew letter Shin on a gematria that refers to the solar calendar, not the lunar one? I can at least get really close in a Shaleim Peshutah year in Eretz Yisrael, but I'm still 3 shy. Maybe the Midrash was rounding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emailed this question to the author of the Sefer and he replied as follows:

> המדרש הזה אבד מספרי המדרשים שלפנינו, והיה לעיני רבותיו הראשונים בלבד.
>   ונאמנת עלינו עדותם.

This Midrash has been lost from our Midroshim and only our Rabbis the Rishonim saw it. We believe their testimony.

(By the way, one of the Rishonim who mention that this is a Midrash is R' Yitzchok Abuhov זצ''ל in מנורת המאור הנר השלישי כלל ג' חלק ה' פרק א' סימן קכ''ו)

Comment: But where do the rishonim attribute it to a midrash?

Comment: @ba One of them is מנורת המאור הנר השלישי כלל ג' חלק ה' פרק א' סימן קכ''ו.

Comment: Maybe you should include the sources for the midrash in your answer

Answer (score 7):

The *Beis Yosef* attributes this to the *Orchos Chayim* in *Orach Chayim* 32 (2/3 down [here](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9C%D7%91)) without mentioning a *midrash*.

> כתב בארחות חיים: לפיכך עושין שי"ן יותר משאר אותיות, כדי לרמוז הימים שאדם מניחם בשנה שהם ש׳.‏

Thanks to @YaacovDeane for the superior citation from *Orchos Chayim* (*T'filin* 27), which brings this idea (*that the Shin hints to the number of days per year that a person is permitted to wear tefillin*) anonymously.

> וכתב בשמושא רבא ב׳ שיני״ן הם הא׳ בימין וא׳ בשמאל ואמניח קאי של ימין מג׳ ראשים ושל שמאל מד׳ ראשים אמנם אם החליף לא פסל. והר׳ בה״ה ז״ל כתב שי״ן של ד׳ ראשים כמו שי״ן של לוחות דהוית מן החקיקה וכן היא נעשית מקמטי העור. טעם למה עושין שי״ן של ד׳ ראשים לפי שספק אם צריכה להיות בולטת או שוקעת ומפני הספק עושין של ימין של בולטת בג׳ ראשים כמשפטה ושל שמאל מד׳ ותהיה בין ראשיה שי״ן שוקעת בת ג׳. **ולפיכך עושין שי״ן יותר משאר אותיות שדי לרמוז הימים שאדם מניחן בשנה שלש מאות כגימטריא של שי״ן** ויזהר שלא יעשה השי״ן בדפוס שאם עשה לא יצא מפני שהיא חק תוכות.

---

<sub>I can't vouch for the version of the *Beis Yosef* I cited, but I corroborated the words I quoted in a bunch of other versions. The addition of the theonym, if it is indeed more correct, explains the absence of a "ה" prefixed on what should be a definite "אותיות", and gives a clue as to the letters "contending" for the spot on *t'filin* being limited to the 3 in this name which has other associations with the *mitzva*, and not the whole alphabet.</sub>

Comment: I do have a copy of Orchot Chaim. The citation appears in Hilchot Tefillin, chapter 27. The relevant section says:

Comment: ואמר אביי שי״ן של תפילין הלכה למשה מסיני. וכתב  בשמושא רבא ב׳ שיני״ן הם הא׳ בימין וא׳  בשמאל ואמניח קאי של ימין מג׳ ראשים ושל שמאל  מד׳  ראשים אמנם אם החליף לא פסל. והר׳ בה״ה ז״ל כתב שי״ן של ד׳ ראשים כמו שי״ן של לוחות דהוית מן החקיקה וכן היא נעשית מקמטי העור. טעם למה עושין שי״ן של ד׳ ראשים לפי שספק אם צריכה להיות בולטת או שוקעת ומפני הספק עושין של ימין של בולטת בג׳ ראשים כמשפטה ושל שמאל מד׳ ותהיה בין ראשיה שי״ן שוקעת בת ג׳. ולפיכך עושין שי״ן יותר משאר אותיות שדי לרמוז הימים שאדם מניחן בשנה שלש מאות כגימטריא של שי״ן ויזהר שלא יעשה השי״ן בדפוס שאם עשה לא יצא מפני שהיא חק תוכות.

Comment: This comment may be a reference to the letter Shin having 3 distinct forms. 1 pointed on the right. 1 pointed on the left, and the 4 headed Shin.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Thank you! I have to go over that again to try to understand it. . . Now do you have a copy of שמשוא רבא?

Comment: Try here: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%90_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%90

Comment: I don’t think the relevant quote is from SR; not only bec. I didn’t see it there but also bec. after OC’s quote from SR about the two *Shin*s the quote is interrupted with “והר׳ בה״ה ז״ל”, which might indicate the rest isn’t from SR [which furthermore explains why BY quoted it from OC and not SR].

Comment: @Oliver I can't say with certainty, but based on the halachic citation,  time period and location, the Rosh Teivot is likely referring to HaRav Baruch ben Shmuel (Hildesheim) of Mainz. He was an early Ashkenazi posek of great note. See this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baruch_ben_Samuel

Comment: @YaacovDeane How do you figure?

Comment: @Oliver Just looking at available Roshei Teivot books and the time of the author (Sefer Orchot Chaim) who quotes a halachic authority in his general geographic region. The ה״ה is a Roshei Teivah of Hildesheim (apparently pronounced Hildes-Heim).

Comment: @YaacovDeane That likeliness is highly unlikely, IMO. IIRC, authorities in that era were hardly referred to by their place of origin/residence when introduced with the title ר׳; IOW, הר׳ הילדסהיים would be very unusual, specially since this R. Baruch was commonly noted as “ממגנצא”.

Comment: @Oliver You mean like Rabbi Meir of Rottenburg? Mainz and Hildesheim were at that time period adjacent, politically disputed territories by the non-Jewish rulers. Hildesheim was slightly north and Mainz to the south.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Correct, I don’t think you’ll find [using your example] הר׳ רוטנברג ז״ל.

Comment: @Oliver Actually, I have seen  הר׳מ מרוטנברג ז״ל. It's not unusual and there is not uniformity of application with Roshei Teivot. During the transition from Rishonim to Acharonim, many started using the name of their locale as a part of their family name. Some of the more traditional Jewish communities in Europe frowned on this type of practice. This became even more of an issue at the time of Napoleon Bonaparte, who insisted that everyone under his rule must adopt a family name by law.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I think you may have missed the point as your example contradicts your hypothesis; הר׳ doesn’t doesn’t precede the place of residence (רוטנבורג), it precedes מ׳ (מאיר).

Comment: @Oliver הר׳  by itself usually stands for 'HaRav'.

Comment: @YaacovDeane And so?